# Decorate a function if condition is True?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do something akin to this, which (understandably) results in a SyntaxError:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
if settings.USE_API_KEY:
    @authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, ))
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def all_announcements(request):
    announcements = Announcement.objects.all()
    serializer = AnnouncementSerializer(announcements, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I implement something similiar to this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would not write a decorator for this - rather note that the decorator syntax allows a function call that returns a decorator (and indeed, this is what decorators-with-parameters actually do). So:

```
def maybe_decorate(condition, decorator):
    return decorator if condition else lambda x: x

@api_view(['GET'])
@maybe_decorate(settings.USE_API_KEY, authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, )))
@maybe_decorate(settings.USE_API_KEY, permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, )))
def all_announcements(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

When you use a decorator like this:

```
@decorator
def f():
    ...
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
def f():
    ...
f = decorator(f)
```

With that in mind, you could accomplish what you want like this:

```
def all_announcements(request):
    announcements = Announcement.objects.all()
    serializer = AnnouncementSerializer(announcements, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

if settings.USE_API_KEY:
    all_announcements = permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))(all_announcements)
    all_announcements = authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))(all_announcements)
all_announcements = api_view(['GET'])(all_announcements)
```

Comment: +1, I would also stick a comment at the top of `all_announcements` to the effect that the name doesn't end up equal to that `def`. The reason is that it's not normal for a reader to see a `def` and think "I must now search through the rest of the file looking for anything that assigns to the name of this function" :-)

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
def my_decorator(condition):
    def wrap(fn):
        def new_f(*args,**kwargs):
            # some code that uses the function fn (fn holds a reference to the function you have decorated)
            pass

        if condition:
            return new_f
        else:
            return fn

    return wrap

@my_decorator(settings.USE_API_KEY)
def all_announcements(request):
    ...
```

(obviously a general example that you will need to apply to your specific code, a lot of which you haven't included in your question so I can't provide a complete example for you to copy paste!)

You can think of this as the `my_decorator(condition)` function returning a new decorator `wrap` which then decorates your function. The decorator `wrap` will use the condition to decide whether to replace your function with new_f or not.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def my_conditional_wrapper(f):

    if not condition():
        return f

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        #wrap function here
        pass

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        if 'usetimer' not in kw:
            return method(*args, **kw)
        elif ('usetimer' in kw and kw.get('usetimer') is None):
            return method(*args, **kw)
        else:
            import time
            ts = time.time()
            result = method(*args, **kw)
            te = time.time()
            if 'log_time' in kw:
                name = kw.get('log_name', method.__name__.upper())
                kw['log_time'][name] = int((te - ts) * 1000)
            else:
                print '%r took %2.2f ms' % \
                      (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000)
            return result
    return timed

def some_func(arg1, **kwargs):
    #do something here

some_func(param1, **{'usetimer': args.usetimer})
```